# Render file without rails tags being interpreted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a requirement where I am trying to render a file through a controller using render. I do not want the rendered file to be interpreted by the rails engine. Is this possible?

i.e

in my controller I have given:

```
render :file => "<file-path>/abc.txt"
```

and the file abc.txt  has the following content:

```
<% if (1) 
Just a piece of code    
 %>
```

Now when the flow reaches render, rails engine tries to interprete the  file and throws an error for an unended if clause. I just want to display the contents of the file without it being interpreted. I have tried with content_type being set to "text" with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
render text: File.open("<file-path>/abc.txt").read
```

Answer (score 0):

Marek answer is good, but make extra sure the file_path is checked so you are not arbitrarily serving any file in the system. You don't want to allow users to serve your database.yml file (with the password on it), the initialization code with your key/secret for signing the cookie (identify theft for any user on your site) or even system files as the shadow password file, ssh keys and so on.